# In Meteor is there way to age out data from a cursor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm thinking about building a log follower similar to the Console on OSX.

Log entries get inserted in the database on the server and are displayed in the client browser.

Meteor seems well-suited for this with its ability to follow a cursor but, my question is:

Is there way to age out older data in the client-side Mongo/Collection and the DOM? (While keeping it all in the server-side Mongo?) Otherwise, the longer you run the more memory you'll use and it's just not sustainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is just to publish the N most recent logs. For example:

```js
Meteor.publish('recentLogs', function () {
  return Logs.find({owner: this.userId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 100});
});
```

In this example, the client would only have the 100 most recent logs that he or she owned.